# Привязка к строке

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Есть вью модель wpf страницы. В ней указано свойство :

```
 string totalST;
 public string totalStproperty
    {
        get { return totalST; }
        set { totalST = value; }
    }
```

В конструкторе класса свойству в первый раз передается значение :

```
totalST = "Всего студентов " + allS.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

И в разметке осуществлена привязка к свойству :

```
   <Label x:Name="allStudents" Content="{Binding totalStproperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

При первой загрузке страницы будет показано общее число студентов, равное строкам в соответствующей таблице. Но затем мы вызываем комманду которая показывает в таблице только часть студентов - соответственно должно поменяться и число в `label`:

```
public RelayCommand<ListBoxItem> SelectFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<ListBoxItem>(DataGridRefresh);
        }
    }
    private void DataGridRefresh(ListBoxItem selected) 
    {   
        totalST= "Всего студентов 0";
    }
```

Ошибок не показывает, компилируется, но выполняется неверно. `totalST` принимает значение `"Всего студентов 0"` но в `Label` так и висит старое значение, словно никакого `Binding` и нет. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе доступа `set` свойства `totalStproperty` должен происходить вызов  метода `RaisePropertyChanged(() => ваше свойство)` для того что бы интерфейс получил уведомление, что значение свойства изменилось.

```
public string totalStproperty
{
    get { return totalST; }
    set 
    { 
        totalST = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => totalStproperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вызов метода не может там находится. ведь в вызываемый метод передается `ListBoxItem` свойство `Content` которого служит параметром для  метода возвращающего новую таблицу а следовательно и число строк не получить. или я что то не понимаю ?

Comment: Что значит `ведь в вызываемый метод передается ListBoxItem`? У вас есть свойство `totalStproperty`, которое привязано к свойству `Label.Content`. Это означает то, что любое изменение значения свойства `totalStproperty` отразится на значение свойства `Label.Content` (ровно как и наоборот, так как привязка `TwoWay`). Но у вас этого не происходит. Почему? А не происходит это потому, как я написал в ответе, что интерфейс не получает уведомления об изменение значения свойства `totalStproperty` (само свойство изменилось, а интерфейс об этом не знает, поэтому автоматически и не обновляет данные).

Comment: Что бы все заработало, необходимо интерфейсу сообщить об изменении свойства `totalStproperty` делается это путем вызова метода `RaisePropertyChanged(() => ваше свойство)` в методе доступа `set`.

Comment: ошибка -  `Ни одна из перегрузок метода "RaisePropertyChanged" не принимает 1 аргументов`

Comment: set
            {
                totalST = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(()=>totalStproperty);
            }

Comment: И  почему интерфейсу не нужно уведомления когда меняется содержимое `DataGrid` ? не потому ли что источником данных для грида служит `ObservableCollection` ?

Comment: `Ни одна из перегрузок метода "RaisePropertyChanged"`. Вы точно используете `GalaSoft.MvvmLight`? Сейчас проверил у себя, все отлично работает.

Comment: да. другого и в `using` нет

Comment: Кажется сам метод нужно расписать `RaisePropertyChanged`....https://acrocontext.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/c-how-raisepropertychanged-works-in-mvvm-light/

Comment: `И почему интерфейсу не нужно уведомления когда меняется содержимое DataGrid ? не потому ли что источником данных для грида служит ObservableCollection ?` Да. Данная коллекция умеет сама уведомлять интерфейс об изменениях.

Comment: надо было использовать `ObservableCollection ` да и не мучаться. спасибо за подсказку

Comment: только как привязать теперь `Content` `Label`а к свойству класса ?

Comment: `только как привязать теперь Content Labelа к свойству класса ?` Что значит привязать к свойству класса, оно ведь и так у вас привязано к свойству `totalStproperty`, которое как я предполагаю расположено в классе какой-то `ViewModel`.